# for loop / unix2dos to clean a group of files with specific extension

Tags: shell, loops, newline, dos2unix

I am trying to use `unix2dos` on a group of C++ source code files. Basically, `unix2dos` converts LF to CRLF.

I could simply do the following, and it does what I want :

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec unix2dos {}\;
```

but I don't want the file to be modified if it has CRLF end of lines already. 
That's why I have to modify the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \)` 
do
  LINE=`file $i | grep CRLF`
  if [ $? -eq 1 ]
  then
    unix2dos $i
  fi
done
```

The `for` loop seems a bit tricky to use since spaces are not being handled correctly. When the filename contains space, the shell is trying to apply unix2dos incorrectly on a splited string.

How do I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your `unix2dos` command with the following (provided by putnamhill upper) :

```
`perl -wpi -e 's/([^\r])\n/$1\r\n/g' $1`;
```

Then do your previous `find` command :

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec unix2dos {}\;
```

And you are all set.

Comment: Very nice. Withtout using perl I think redefining an alias for `unix2dos` and applying itself only if needed works as well. `find -exec` is the most natural form for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following perl, which should leave CRLF files unchanged:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec perl -pi -e 's/([^\r])\n/$1\r\n/' "{}"\;
```

It will insert a CR before any LF that isn't preceded by a CR.

Answer (score 1):

- You shouldn't process find command's output in a for loop.
- You need to quote your variables properly in shell.

Try this code instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) | while read i
do
  LINE=`file "$i" | grep -c CRLF`
  if [ $LINE -eq 0 ]
  then
    unix2dos "$i"
  fi
done
```

**UPDATE:** If you decide to use BASH then you can do this looping more efficiently. Consider following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file
do
  grep -q $'\r'"$" "$file" && unix2dos "$file"
done < <(find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \))
```

`< <(...)` syntax is called [**process substitution**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) that makes above while loop in the current shell itself thus allowing you to set shel variables in current shell process and saving a forking of sub-shell creation.

Comment: But you used a `while` loop. What I want to do seems impossible with `for` loop but I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks anyway it does the job.

Comment: Yes doing a `while` loop as I showed is the right way when filename can contain whitespaces or newlines.

Comment: @JohnPoe: Are you facing any problem in this answer?

Comment: Your answer is good. I'm trying to figure out the most elegant solution and wait for more answers.

Comment: Can you use BASH by chance? This answer can be made more elegant and efficient in BASH.

Comment: Yes, you can give the answer anyway for others who would encounter the same problem. Please tell us the advantages of using bash also.

Answer (score 1):

You could check with a `grep` if a file contains a `\r` and run `unix2dos` conditionally, like this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -exec sh -c 'grep -q ^M "{}" && dos2unix "{}"' \;
```

... where you enter `^M` by pressing Control-V and Enter. (`^M` is the `\r` character)

Comment: Please explain what `^M` is for.

Comment: It's the `\r` character

Answer (score 0):

Unix2dos will change LF to CRLF, but it will not change CRLF to CRCRLF. Any existing DOS line break will stay unchanged. So the simplest way to do what you want is:

unix2dos *.h *.cpp

best regards,
Erwin

Comment: I don't want the file to be modified at all if it is already OK. Source code control can detect that the file changed if you apply unix2dos on a "clean file".